# How to port enums with assigned values from C to Java?

Tags: java, c, enums

I am trying to port a very simple app from C to Java.
Unfortunately I haven't worked quite a lot with enums before so the following code confuses me:

```
typedef enum {
    LT = 0,
    LTE = 1,
    E = 2,
    GTE = 3,
    GT = 4
} S;
```

From my understanding the numbers are the values which represent every enum.

How could I do the same in Java?

Should I take this approach

```
private enum S{
    LT,
    LTE,
    E,
    GTE,
    GT
}
```

or

This approach?

```
private enum S{
    LT(0),
    LTE(1),
    E(2),
    GTE(3),
    GT(4);      

    private int code; 

    S(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    } 
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

If the enumeration in Java already starts from 0 it would be a little redundant to add the second method. I am confused...

Comment: Enums in C and C++ and C# start from 0, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it the first way. The great thing about `enum` constants in Java is that they are *not* `int` values, so you do not need to assign values to them in this way.

If for some reason you need to know the index of an `enum` constant (and this is rare), you can do `LT.ordinal()` anyway.